# Web user activity tracking [standalone offline library]

Tags: javascript, analytics, tracking

Somebody knows if there are any good FREE JS library for user frontend session tracking? It would help to understand what causes some errors. But this tool mustn't be sending something somewhere online (for use in enterprise system where send such data is unacceptable)

Answer (score 1):

You can selfhost [piwik](https://piwik.org/) and setup custom events which shall be tracked.